# Replacing Oracle Discoverer

Tags: oracle-database

Oracle Discoverer as been discontinued by Oracle. Oracle suggests to switch to BIPublisher but it seems to be to expensive and a bit to much for what we need.

What we really need is a opensource or commercial tool that:

- allows the developer team to create reports
- able to create reports that have query conditions (values given by the client or set by the developer team when the report is created)
- offer report scheduling (since, as it is now, some reports take hours to complete because of the data volume)
- reports may be request by the client anytime they want (with or without using the scheduler).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.